# include linearlayout from other layout android

Tags: android, xml, layout

I have a `layout.xml` panel in `android(R.layout.items)`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="textview1: " />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/Panel1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="1dp" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/agente2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:maxLength="5"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/agente2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:singleLine="true" >
    </EditText>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/Panel2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="1dp" >
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cbTipoIncidente1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CheckBox" />
.....
```

In this panel I have some `linearlayout` that I want to add dynamically and programatically to another `layout(r.layout.other)`:

With inflate I can only add `r.layout` resources and not `r.id`. I'd like to add single view(for example panel1) to `r.layout.other`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save that `LinearLayout` as separate `panel.xml` and call in different `layout.xml` files using `<include>` tag as below:

```
   <LinearLayout ... >
         <include layout="@layout/panel" />
  </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I can't save every single panel in others xml, because are many; isn't possibile adding dinamically from the single res R.layout.items r.layout.other to r.layout.other?

Comment: This is the way to call common layout part and include in other xml files.

Answer (score 2):

Use this concept

```
LinearLayout global_panel = new LinearLayout (this);
        global_panel.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        global_panel.setGravity(Gravity.FILL);
        global_panel.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back);
```